# Why does Firebug not show "Uncaught ReferenceError" errors?

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

How do I make Firebug catch a reference error?

Using Firefox with Firebug enabled I wasted time trying to figure out what was wrong with my HTML/jQuery page.

Then I went to Chrome and used its DevTools, and sure enough there it was, an "Uncaught ReferenceError" that's causing some elements not to show.

The code is:

```
final_date_from = '2014-01-01'; 
$("#notice").html(' (' + final_date_from + " to " + final_date_to + ") ");
```

(as you can see I've not set the `final_date_to` variable.)

What I see in the Chrome DevTools:

[image: Display of the reference error in Chrome DevTools]

I created a [simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rMHe/) demonstrating the error.

Why doesn't this get caught in Firebug?

Comment: If you don't use `var` it generally isn't a blocking error and will be defined in global window namespace. You can have unexpected behavior which is possibly what happened. Have you declared `"use strict"` or has it been declared anywhere in the same scope as your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the option Show JavaScript Errors enabled:

[image: Show JavaScript Errors option within Console panel options menu]

Then you'll see a similar error message within the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel):

[image: JavaScript error displayed within Console panel]